# What type of sensor has diamond pinout like shown? Resistive bridge? Wheatstone?

Tags: sensor, signal, pinout, wheatstone-bridge

[image]

I have worked with basic resistive sensors before, but I have never seen a pinout like this one and I'm not sure how the voltages work for these pins. I was told it may be a resistive bridge, but it seems to me there are some differences between this one and the examples I've seen in articles. I also don't see much of an explanation in the datasheet for this sensor (a pressure sensor):

http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/589/-219572.pdf

I am not sure what other terms I can search for to understand how to use this sensor in my project. Is it a resistive bridge? If so, how does this one differ from a basic example (i.e. why does it seem to be separated down the middle instead of connected?). What is the theory of operation? What are the meanings of +V exc, -V exc, +Sig, -Sig and so on? Any information would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the diagram next to it in the datasheet. That is nothing more than a Wheatstone bridge, with extra pins broken out. Tie the +Vexc pins together, as well as the -Vexc pins, or use the version that doesn't break out the extra pins.

Comment: So just to clarify, if I connect V+exc1/sub with +Vexc, as well as the two -Vexc together it's the same as any Wheatstone bridge?

Comment: @JoeyDodson Yep

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! I guess breaking those out is what threw me off. If you don't mind, is there a benefit to breaking those pins out like this? Some other configuration perhaps?

Comment: @JoeyDodson Maybe if you wanted to do 2 absolute measurements, but that's a stretch. Usually you want to do these types of measurements ratiometrically.